# How to disable sorting while checking condition for parameter value in ssrs 2008

Tags: ssrs-2008

We have added parameter, which have default value 0, But I want that when parameter value is greater that 0 at this time sorting should be disable. Any idea regarding it.
In other words I want to disable sorting as per the condition.

Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about static sorting or interactive sorting?

Comment: I am talking about interactive sorting.